# Magento install won't run due to version

Tags: magento-1.9, database, mamp

I am trying to install magento, and i tried everything for what i can do, updating mysql, creating a .bash file in / with file bath to mysql.But all fail. When i run magento-check.php (a script to check if your upto date with all requirment for magento), it tell me your on mysql version 4.x. Whereas phpmyadmin mention something like 5.x version. 
I tried installing bitnami magento but it came with magento 2, so not useful for me, as i am trying to run magento 1.9 and greater. 
Can someone help me out, i am beyond frustrated. It never happened to be before.

Comment: Please check `phpinfo()` for **safe_mode** and if it's On try to change it to **Off**.

Comment: @michael it is set to off already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After day of trying to figure out, after looking through the logs and finding the error

> "sh: mysql: command not found"

I created a .bash_profile in my ~/ and paste the following in it

> export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin

The above mentioned steps are posted [here](http://www.webbykat.com/2012/06/solving-sh-mysql-command-not-found-mamp-pro-2)

.

Saved, and restarted the MAMP, and it fixed. I hope this help everyone who is finding it hard to fix the error, which should be logged by MAMP or Magento docs.